# Converting time datatype to xxhxxmxxs

Tags: postgresql, datetime-format, postgresql-8.4

I wonder if there is any function in postgres that can easily convert values stored as 00:00:00 to more human friendly format: 3h 5m ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [to_char](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html) function:

```
select to_char(cast('05:03:00' as time), 'HH24h MIm SSs');
```

This will produce

```
05h 03m 00s
```